# Howto check for existing aggregate functions in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

In Postgresql you can create additional Aggregate Functions with

```
CREATE AGGREGATE name(...);
```

But this gives an error if the aggregate already exists inside the database, so how can I check if a Aggregate already exists in the Postgres Database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'name' AND proisagg;
```

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/catalogs-overview.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/catalog-pg-aggregate.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/catalog-pg-proc.html

Answer (score -1):

```
drop aggregate if exists my_agg(varchar);

create aggregate my_agg(varchar) (...);

select * from pg_aggregate
where aggfnoid = 'my_agg'::regproc;
```